# Git how to ignore files in .gitignore from checkout

Tags: git

I am quite new in git, so my question may sound familiar with you, 
I have 2 branches DEV and STAGING, I have a DB config file which I don't want push or pull, I created an `.gitignore` file in my local branch (in root not in .git) and I didn't push it to the remote.
Any time I checkout to STAGING I get a message that my config file has local changes and will be overwritten.
Should I push my .gitignore to the remote branche? (if yes, to DEV or STAGING)

[image]

Comment: yes push it to DEV and STAGING both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message means that the config file has previously been committed to STAGING. Since the file is committed it cannot be ignored. You will need to remove the config file completely with

```
$ git rm <db config file>
$ git commit -m 'Remove db config file'
```

assuming you are on the STAGING branch.

Comment: Thank you, I think this is what was missing